# Обращение к определенным буквам в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть такая вот задача:

> Есть список `list = ['hello', 'hi', 'hola', 'hey']`. Надо из этого
>   списка составить новый список, который будет состоять из каждой второй
>   буквы из списка.

Я понимаю, как обратиться с элементу списка, но как от туда выбрать эти буквы не понимаю.

Мой код:

```
list = ['hello', 'hi', 'hola', 'hey']
newList = []

for letter in list:
    newList.append(list[2])
print(newList)
```

Comment: x = [i[1] for i in list] . Только не называйте больше переменную "list". Это зарезервированное системой слово в Python

Answer (score 3):

У вас почти получилось, но:

- Нужно было обращаться к второму элементу (индексация в питоне начинается с `0`, поэтому второй элемент будет иметь индекс `1`)
- В цикле нужно было не к списку обращаться, а к его элементам

Пример:

```
items = ['hello', 'hi', 'hola', 'hey']

new_list = []
for letter in items:
    new_list.append(letter[1])

print(new_list)
# ['e', 'i', 'o', 'e']
```

Через списочное выражение:

```
items = ['hello', 'hi', 'hola', 'hey']
new_list = [x[1] for x in items]
print(new_list)
# ['e', 'i', 'o', 'e']
```

---

**PS.**

Думаю, имеет смысл добавить наглядный пример почему нельзя использовать built-in имена, такие как [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list):

```
print(list('hello'))
# ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']

list = ['hello', 'hi', 'hola', 'hey']

print(list('hello'))
# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Как видно, обращение будет к переменной с таким же именем, это простой способ "выстрелить себе в ногу".

Comment: В цикле нужно было не к списку обращаться, а к его элементам. Вот этого, просто ни где не мог найти. И приносит здесь захват вопрос. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял задачу:

```py
base_list = ['hello', 'hi', 'hola', 'hey']
new_list = [word[1] for word in base_list]
print(new_list) # ['e', 'i', 'o', 'e']
```

Если вы имели в виду не каждую вторую букву в слове, а каждую вторую букву от всего списка, то нужно другое решение, напишите в комменты.

P. S. `list` - это очень плохое имя для переменной, т.к. это зарезервированное слово в python.